# tkinter program hanging on button click

Tags: python, button, tkinter, lag, freeze

I'm making a small program for calculating weighted grades for college classes. Mostly just doing it to experiment with python tkinter. On the one and only window I have four entries, along with four labels, and four buttons. These are for getting the number of weighted sections, the names of the weighted sections, the weights, and the points earned, respectively. There is also a fifth button at the bottom for calculating the grade.

I'm running into an issue where many times that the last button is pressed there is a 2 or 3 second delay before the associated event handler is called. I've tried structuring the program several different ways, and keep running into to the same issue. Right now I've got the tkinter mainloop running on its own thread, and another thread where all of the event handling happens. Its strange, because if I click off of the tkinter window putting focus somewhere else before clicking the button, it doesn't usually hang. But if I go straight from using the four entries to clicking the button, then it usually does hang. If I completely ignore the entries all together, and just click the bottom button, there is never any hanging. To be specific, when I click the button, it isn't until 2 or 3 seconds later that the button's callback begins executing.

It is the `generate_report_btn` command defined in `view.py` that is hanging. The function that it calls is `generate_report` inside `command.py`

I structured my code similarly to instructions that I found in a Medium post [here](https://medium.com/@mattia512maldini/how-to-setup-correctly-an-application-with-python-and-tkinter-107c6bc5a45).

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

### model.py

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    q = Queue()
    view_ref = view(root, q)
    model = SimpleNamespace(
        names_count=0,
        weights_count=0,
        points_count=0,
        number_of_sections=0,
        sections={},
    )
    t = Thread(target=controller, args=(view_ref, model, q,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    tk.mainloop()
```

### view.py

```py
def view(root, q):

    root.minsize(900, 700)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=75)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=400)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    # Define main window widgets
    main_frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="8 8 8 200")


    # (...)

    # Generate Report widgets
    generate_report_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
    generate_report_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    generate_report_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    generate_report_btn = ttk.Button(
        generate_report_frame,
        text="Generate Report",
        command=lambda: q.put(controller.Messages.GENERATE_REPORT),
    )


    # Grid main_frame
    main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    # (...)

    # Grid generate report widgets
    generate_report_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    generate_report_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, sticky="s")

    # (...)


    return SimpleNamespace(
        lbl2_var=lbl2_var,
        lbl3_var=lbl3_var,
        lbl4_var=lbl4_var,
        entry1_var=entry1_var,
        entry2_var=entry2_var,
        entry3_var=entry3_var,
        entry4_var=entry4_var,
        btn1=btn1,
        entry1=entry1,
        btn3=btn3,
        entry3=entry3,
        btn4=btn4,
        entry4=entry4,
        btn2=btn2,
        entry2=entry2,
    )
```

### controller.py

```py
# (...)

def generate_report():
    print("generate_report")


def controller(view_ref, model, q):
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        if msg == Messages.GET_NUMBER_OF_SECTIONS:
            # (...)
        elif msg == Messages.GET_SECTION_NAME:
            # (...)
        elif msg == Messages.GET_SECTION_WEIGHT:
            # (...)
        elif msg == Messages.GET_SECTION_POINTS:
            # (...)
        elif msg == Messages.GENERATE_REPORT:
            generate_report()
```

Comment: Could you try to remove unrelated parts from your code until you have a minimal example that exhibits the issue? This is a lot of code for a SO question.

Comment: most GUI frameworks don't like to run in threads (not only in Python). You can run calculations in separated thread but widgets have to run in main thread. Other problem that Python has GIL and it runs only one thread a time - and other threads have to wait.

Comment: @furas this makes sense, but before running it like this I was using a single threaded OOP approach, and had the same type of problem.

Comment: I can't run your code to see if this problem is on other computers (and/or systems)

Answer (score 1):

`tkinter` doesn't support multithreading, in the sense that all interactions with it and associated widgets (i.e. the GUI) must occur *within* the same thread.

Comment: I was using an OOP approach before this, with no multi-threading, and had same issue. I  read in several places that tkinter does now support multi-threading. Is that not correct?

Comment: All I can say is I've never heard of it supporting multithreading — just the opposite. If you were having the problem even when not using it, then the issue is probably due to something taking too long and interrupting the `mainloop()`.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too, with respect to the `mainloop()`. It seems to having something to do with the processing of the `ttk.Entry` objects, because when they're not in the program nothing like this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with printing out to the console. I was using print statements in the function that was associated with the lagging, for debugging purposes. I took out those print statements, and focused on just updating the GUI, and I haven't encountered the issue since. Hopefully that is it.

Just wanted to post this for clarification in case someone with a similar issue comes across this thread in the future.